# How to write a test case with moq ApplicationUser, ApplicationContextdb, IEmailSender and IConfirguration

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

Need your help to how to write a unit test case in ASP.net core identity user.

In Current design we My controller using dependency Injection. It injecting all  below class

- ApplicationUser "used for identity purpose"
- ApplicationDbContext  " used for entity framework"
- Iemailsender   " userd for to send Mail"
- IConfiguration  "Iconfirguration purpose "

I have controller which have dependency injection how to moq all the parameters using x unit.

I have tried the below things, but not sure how to mock all the interface dependency injection class. Please find the below controller.

when i'm running this test _userManager user list is null. please help me on this how the data will come to _usermanger

```
//This below m controller for which i need to write a x unit testcase 
   public UsersController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext,
        IEmailSender emailService,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        _emailService = emailService;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
   //controller Method for which i need to write a test case 
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("User")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AppUser([FromQuery] string username)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
      return ok(user);
    }

  // This is my test message which I'm writing 
   ApplicationUser testUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "testuser1"};     
        var mockStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> 
       (mockStore.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        mockStore.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(appuser, 
       It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
      .Returns(Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success));
        mockStore.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(testUser.UserName, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                     .Returns(Task.FromResult(testUser));
        var fakeEmailSender = new Mock<IEmailSender>();
        var fakeConfiguration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();

        var Controller = new UsersController(mockUserManager.Object, 
          context, fakeEmailSender.Object, fakeConfiguration.Object);
        var res = Controller.AppUser("testuser1");
     }
```

Comment: Well, I assume you have to assign something to `_userManager` (and your other dependencies), probably your mocked instance. However how should we know how that instance should look like? Are you asking us how to mock them? Did you look in the docs of Moq, e.g. https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart?

Comment: Without at least some basics about mocking this question is going to be far too broad. We can´t know how your mocks should behave.

Comment: In particular you didn´t provide any information on where and how you´re using the dependencies. E.g. where is `_userManager` used? How should the manager behave when you call a member on it?

Comment: I'm using like this to moc the  below code var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockUserStore.Object); but getting the error. If i use like this Moc<Applicationuser> but not able to pass as pareameter

Comment: Eeeehm, what? Could you please edit your question with that information? I don´t get the picture here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Hi, I edited my question could you please check and suggest me if i'm missing anything out here